# ARAnchor / SCNNode relation

Tags: scenekit, arkit

Using ARKit, I have a use case where I need, from a touch event to retrieve the touched Node, and update it with some of its Anchor information.

With ARKit, I can retrieve the touched anchor, but then, how to get the related node ?

or

With SceneKit, I can retrieve the touched node, but then, how to get the related anchor ?

The only I found was to maintain a relationship table myself, using the various delegate's calls. Is there any smarter way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ARSCNView` class exposes both [`-anchorForNode:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/2875546-anchorfornode) and [`-nodeForAnchor:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/2874122-nodeforanchor).